# Name '...' doesn't exit in current context

Tags: c#, struct

I am a beginner in C# right now and my task is to write in console all the details of a product. I have to use the struct. I made a `Product` struct.
The function `writeProducts` cannot see the `prod1` and all of its details.

However I get an error CS0103 that the name doesn't exist in current context and I don't know where I made a mistake.

Sorry, English is not my native language.

```
namespace project
{
    class Program
    {
        public struct Product
        {
            public string Name;
            public string Type;
            public double Pr1pc;
            public double Pr1kg;
            public int number;
        }
       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Product prod1;

            //Prod1
            prod1.Name = "Chlyb";
            prod1.Type = "szt";
            prod1.Pr1pc = 6.30;
            prod1.number = 1;

            writeProducts();

            Console.ReadKey();
            Main(args);
        }
        static void writeProducts()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}. {0},{0}{0}", prod1.number, prod1.Name, prod1.Pr1pc, prod1.Type);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Product prod1;` only exists in the `Main` function. `writeProducts()` can't access it. One solution is to pass it as a parameter. `writeProducts(prod1);` and `static void writeProducts(Product prod) { // Use prod here }`

Comment: There is still some error, CS0165 at `writeProducts(prod1);`

Comment: "Rule-Of-Thumb": Every var is only visible inside the "{}" it has been declared in or in nested ones. There are exceptions from that "rule" but for a first check when you get that error it is ok.

Comment: _"Use of unassigned local variable 'name'"_ - [CS0165](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0165) - show the updated code.

Comment: _"I have to use the struct."_ - Does the assignment _explicitly_ say `struct`? That would be rather odd for a beginners' course.

Comment: Have a look into [Struct initialization and default values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#struct-initialization-and-default-values). You declared it, but you didn't init it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've made an error with trying to read a variable from another method and there was an error with declaring a variable (an answer below). Thank you very much to all of you guys

Comment: Because you did not use `new` you have to manually initialize all fields. You did not initialize `prod1.Pr1kg`. This only applies to structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared the variable `prod1` in the `Main` function, so it is not recognized in the `writeProducts` function. Try to send the `prod1` as a parameter to `writeProducts` like that:

```
class Program
    {
        public struct Product
        {
            public string Name;
            public string Type;
            public double Pr1pc;
            public double Pr1kg;
            public int number;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Product prod1 = new();

            //Prod1
            prod1.Name = "Chlyb";
            prod1.Type = "szt";
            prod1.Pr1pc = 6.30;
            prod1.number = 1;


            writeProducts(prod1);


            Console.ReadKey();
            Main(args);



        }
        static void writeProducts(Product prod)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("{0}. {0},{0}{0}", prod.number, prod.Name, prod.Pr1pc, prod.Type);
        }
    }
}
```

Also notice you need to use the `new` word when declaring `prod1`

Comment: Thanks a lot. The lecturer actually send us some notes about creating a new variable like prod1 by: `Product prod1;` instead of `Product prod1=new();`.
No errors right now, thank you so much!

Comment: please vote for my answer if it helped you

Comment: As soon as I get the reputation, mate! New account here so I can't vote yet